# Module 'jaxlib.xla_extension.jax_jit' has no attribute 'set_enable_x64_cpp_flag'

Tags: python, jax

I've tried to install jax.lib on win10. It seems like jax.lib is installed but when I run the spyder and write 'import jax', it says

> module 'jaxlib.xla_extension.jax_jit' has no attribute
> 'set_enable_x64_cpp_flag'

I have python 3.10 and cuda version 11.6.

Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded JAX by writing

> pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib

on the anaconda command prompt and the problem is resolved.